# Robotium - click on content-desc and start test on running activity

Tags: android, android-layout, robotium, android-uiautomator

**1st Question**

I'm trying go click on button near to menuItem (on galaxy s6) with robotium. Here is the [button](https://scr.hu/)

Here is the class and the content-desc of this button from [UI Automator Viewer](https://scr.hu/)

I was trying to click on it with many ways but i can't.. For example I can click on the next one button just with `solo.clickOnMenuItem("string");` because this one one has  content-desc: Menu.

So how can I click the 1st one?

**2nd question**

Can I start robotium test on opened apk? I mean I open manually my application, log on my user account, and then I leave next activity opened. Then I run robotium test with:

```
adb shell am instrument -w -e class com.android.foo.FooTest com.android.foo/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner
```

and the test begins from that activity, I need that for making some automated presentations.

All test that I was running where starting apk on itself, but how can I skip it?